# overflow: scroll not working in UIWebView in iOS 8

Tags: css, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, ios8

In iOS 8, I have the following code in web page in a `UIWebVIew`,

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS,

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#outer {
    overflow: scroll;
}
#middle {
    width: 160%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#inner {
    background: red;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

In iOS 7, this works to give a sideways scrollable div in the web view. But in iOS 8, the div is *not* sideways scrollable.

Any ideas? I've tried `overflow: auto`, too, with no success.

Answer (score 3):

Add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to your `#inner` block.